# How to fix a org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I'm using spark 2.2. and a job 1 writes randomly, in a rare case, a corrupted parquet files. From this job point of view, everything is fine and SUCCESS file is written. Because it happens rarely, it seems to be some kind of race condition …

In the job, I do something like :

```
df.groupBy("a.id").agg(first("a"))
```

When I try to read the generated parquet from job 2, I have this error.

If I run again the job 1 on the same data, it succeeds and writes a non corrupted file.

- Q1 : Why the write process is not aware of the corruption ?
- Q2 : Is there a way to solve/workaround that issue ?

---

```
[WARN ] 2018-01-11 08:53:58,482 org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager - Lost task 42.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 44, ip-10-0-183-241.eu-west-1.compute.internal, executor 2): org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at 0 in block -1 in file s3a:/[…]/part-00464-28a87f47-10af-444d-8b49-3bf4fc37fe90-c000.snappy.parquet
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:223)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(ParquetRecordReader.java:215)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:105)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:177)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:105)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectAggregationIterator.processInputs(ObjectAggregationIterator.scala:191)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectAggregationIterator.<init>(ObjectAggregationIterator.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectHashAggregateExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$2.apply(ObjectHashAggregateExec.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectHashAggregateExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$2.apply(ObjectHashAggregateExec.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: could not decode the dictionary for [publisher_context, referer_deep_three] BINARY
at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnReaderImpl.<init>(ColumnReaderImpl.java:348)
at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnReadStoreImpl.newMemColumnReader(ColumnReadStoreImpl.java:82)
at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnReadStoreImpl.getColumnReader(ColumnReadStoreImpl.java:77)
at org.apache.parquet.io.RecordReaderImplementation.<init>(RecordReaderImplementation.java:271)
at org.apache.parquet.io.MessageColumnIO$1.visit(MessageColumnIO.java:120)
at org.apache.parquet.io.MessageColumnIO$1.visit(MessageColumnIO.java:107)
at org.apache.parquet.filter2.compat.FilterCompat$FilterPredicateCompat.accept(FilterCompat.java:127)
at org.apache.parquet.io.MessageColumnIO.getRecordReader(MessageColumnIO.java:107)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.checkRead(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:136)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:194)
... 27 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: FAILED_TO_UNCOMPRESS(5)
at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.throw_error(SnappyNative.java:98)
at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.rawUncompress(Native Method)
at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.uncompress(Snappy.java:547)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.codec.SnappyDecompressor.decompress(SnappyDecompressor.java:69)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.codec.NonBlockedDecompressorStream.read(NonBlockedDecompressorStream.java:51)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
at org.apache.parquet.bytes.BytesInput$StreamBytesInput.toByteArray(BytesInput.java:205)
at org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainBinaryDictionary.<init>(PlainValuesDictionary.java:89)
at org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainBinaryDictionary.<init>(PlainValuesDictionary.java:72)
at org.apache.parquet.column.Encoding$1.initDictionary(Encoding.java:90)
at org.apache.parquet.column.Encoding$4.initDictionary(Encoding.java:149)
at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnReaderImpl.<init>(ColumnReaderImpl.java:343)
... 36 more
```